# If you are dying, are you still bloodied?

Tags: dnd-4e

There are some powers that allow you to keep fighting when dying. Do you still count as bloodied if your HP are at 0 or less?

Comment: Do those powers specifically say "when dying"? because (RC page 29 and page 356), a character who is dying is unconscious and prone, so the powers should account for that, at least. Even if so, what would it matter if the character was bloodied or not?

Comment: @Adriano - There are indeed feats and powers that allow one to remain conscious and continue acting beyond zero HP. Technically though, most of those powers do remove the dying status or delay it from taking effect. Take a look at some of the Revenant class features and feats, for good examples.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the PHB, page 293, **yes**.

Unless, of course, zero or fewer hitpoints is greater than half your maximum hit points.