# Does bringing a minion to 0 hit points count as bloodying it?

Tags: dnd-4e, minion

Does killing a minion trigger abilities and feats that work when someone bloodies a creature?

Example:

> **[Markings of the Predator](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1850)<sup>DDI</sup>**
>   **Prerequisite:** Goliath, any primal class
>   **Benefit:** When you bloody a creature, you gain a +1 bonus to all defenses until the end of your next turn.
>   *Published in Primal Power, page(s) 140.*

Comment: Thank you for the editing, okeefe, is much clearer and cleaner now. ^_^

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**No**,

Not only don't minions trigger such effects but neither does **any** creature that is killed while not previously bloodied.

From the *Rules Compendium*, pg257:

> When an unbloodied creature is killed outright, the creature does not become bloodied in the process.  It is just dead.  This rule means a minion ... is bloodied only if an attacker reduces the minion to 0 hit points but knocks it unconscious ... instead of killing it.

Answer (score 9):

I would rule this one as a **No**.

From DDI - Minions: **A minion is destroyed when it takes any damage.** If a minion is missed by an attack that deals damage on a miss, the minion doesn’t take that damage.

I take this to mean that a minion can not be bloodied in the normal sense, since it either is at full HP or it is dead.  A dead opponent is not considered bloodied for rules purposes so, I would rule this one, a no.

As a followup and side note; check out this link on [Dying and Bloodied](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5703/if-you-are-dying-are-you-still-bloodied).  Since Dying is not dead this group has indicated, and I agree, that a dying character is still considered bloodied.  There seems to be a strong distinction between Dead and Dying were bloodied is concerned.

Dungeon masters take note: Creatures with enhanced powers on bloodied character status can still get them with dying characters.